# $K_0$ group of an infinite factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, von-neumann-algebras

The following question was already posted in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342955) but I could not understand hints given in this post.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite factor and my question is how to prove that $K_0(\mathcal{M})$ is trivial. Let $q\in\mathcal{M}$ be a proper projection that is Murray-von Neumann equivalent to the identity $I$ and let $\sim$ denote the Murray-von Neumann equivalence. Then I can show that if $p\in\mathcal{M}$ is a projection and $p\perp q$, then $q\sim q+p$, which implies that $[p]_0=0$. However, to obtain the desired conclusion I need that, for any projections $p_1, p_2\in M_N(\mathcal{M})$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $[q]_0+[p_1]_0 = [q]_0+[p_2]_0$. Any hints or references will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $q$ is equivalent to $I$ in $M_N(\mathcal{M})$ for all $N$, so repeating your earlier argument gives what you need.

Comment: More precisely, since $\mathcal{M}$ is an infinite factor, there exists a projection $q$ equivalent to $I$ such that $I$ is the infinite sum of countably many pairwise orthogonal projections equivalent to $q$. You should then be able to prove $q$ is equivalent to $I$ in $M_n(\mathcal{M})$ for any $n$. Choosing $n = N + 1$, then $[q]_0 + [p]_0$ is represented by $q \oplus p \in M_n(\mathcal{M})$. You already know in this case that $q$ is then equivalent to $q \oplus p$ in $M_n(\mathcal{M})$, so $[q]_0 + [p]_0 = [q]_0$ and then $[p]_0 = 0$.

Comment: As a remark, a far more natural choice for the K-theory of type II_∞ factors is to start with the category of modules (or W*-modules) of a finite von Neumann dimension.  In this case, we do get a meaningful K-theory group, namely, **R**.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you for your hints and your first comment is the main difficulty I have. It is clear that in $M_n(\mathcal{M})$, the identity $I_n$ is equivalent to $\bigoplus_{1\leq i \leq n}q$. However, I do not how to prove $q$ is equivalent to $I_n$. Once this is done, as you mentioned any projections $p\in M_n(\mathcal{M})$ is perpendicular to $q\oplus 0_{n-1}$.

Comment: @DavidGao In your second comment, I suppose you are referring to the halving property of the identity. Is this true precisely when $\mathcal{M}$ is properly infinite, or you mean an infinite factor is automatically properly infinite?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya: M-modules of a finite von Neumann dimension are precisely finite direct sums of M-modules of the form pM, where p is a finite projection in M.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I see. Then how are these $W^*$-modules related to the $K$-theory of a type $II_{\infty}$ factor?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya: Every module of a finite von Neumann dimension is also a finitely generated projective module.  However, there are finitely generated projective modules of an infinite dimension, e.g., M itself, if M is a type II_∞ factor.  That's why the usual K-theory of a type II_∞ factor is trivial, but if you take the K-theory of modules of a finite von Neumann dimension, you get a nontrivial K-group, namely, **R**.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya A vNa is properly infinite if no nontrivial central projection is finite, so an infinite factor is automatically properly infinite. Then for a properly infinite algebra, you can divide the identity into any number (finite or countably infinite) of mutually orthogonal projections, all equivalent to the identity. In particular, $I = q_1 + \cdots + q_N$ where $q_i$'s are mutually orthogonal and all equivalent to $I$. Then $q_i \otimes e_{11}$ is equivalent to $q_i \otimes e_{ii}$ in $M_n(\mathcal{M})$. ($q_i \otimes e_{1i}$ is a partial isometry connecting them.)

Comment: @SanaeKochiya After that, you have $I_{\mathcal{M}} = e_{11} = \sum_{i = 1}^N q_i \otimes e_{11}$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i = 1}^N q_i \otimes e_{ii}$. Since $q_i$ are all equivalent to $I_{\mathcal{M}}$, we have $q_1 \sim I_{\mathcal{M}} \sim \sum_{i = 1}^N q_i \otimes e_{ii} \sim \sum_{i = 1}^N I_{\mathcal{M}} \otimes e_{ii} = I_n$.

Comment: @DavidGao Very nice hints! The fact that a infinite factor is properly infinite is, unfortunately, subtle to me and that is exactly what I need. If you do not mind, could you briefly write down your idea so that I can give you the reputation points?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks for your explanation and now your point is clear to me. However, I am not used to understand $K$-theory, or use knowledge from modules to solve $K$-theory problems. I have heard that this is one starting point of generalizing $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras to the one for an abstract ring, but based on what I have learnt, I am not there yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a more streamlined version of the answer I provided in the comments:

We first observe that an infinite factor is properly infinite. (This is because a von Neumann algebra is defined to be properly infinite if all its nonzero central projections are infinite. In a factor, the only nonzero central projection is the infinite projection $I$, as the center is $\mathbb{C}$ and the only nonzero projection there is $I$.) In a properly infinite algebra, we may divide the identity into any number (finite or countably infinite) of pairwise orthogonal projections, each one equivalent to $I$. (See, for example, Theorem 49.7 in Conway's *A course in operator theory*.) In particular, we may write $I = \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} q_i$, where $q_i$'s are pairwise orthogonal and all equivalent to $I$. We now show that for any projection $p \in M_N(\mathcal{M})$, $[I_1]_0 + [p]_0 = [I_1]_0$, which implies $[p]_0 = 0$ and hence $K_0(\mathcal{M})$ is trivial.

We observe that $[I_1]_0$ can be represented by $e_{11} \in M_{N + 1}(\mathcal{M})$. Note then that $e_{11} = \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} e_{11} \otimes q_i$. Note that $e_{1i} \otimes q_i$ is a partial isometry connecting $e_{11} \otimes q_i$ to $e_{ii} \otimes q_i$, whence $e_{11} \otimes q_i \sim e_{ii} \otimes q_i$ in $M_{N + 1}(\mathcal{M})$. Hence, $e_{11} = \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} e_{11} \otimes q_i \sim \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} e_{ii} \otimes q_i$. Since all $q_i$ are equivalent to $I$ in $\mathcal{M}$, we see that $e_{11} \sim \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} e_{ii} \otimes q_i \sim \sum_{i = 1}^{N + 1} e_{ii} \otimes I = I_{N + 1}$.

Now, $[I_1]_0 + [p]_0$ can be represented by $e_{11} \oplus p \in M_{N + 1}(\mathcal{M})$. Therefore, $e_{11} \leq e_{11} \oplus p \leq I_{N + 1} \sim e_{11}$. Hence, $e_{11} \sim e_{11} \oplus p$, so $[I_1]_0 + [p]_0 = [I_1]_0$.